# Hibernation date and time registry in Debian 8

Tags: debian, users, login, hibernate

I was wondering if there is some log file where I can find the dates and times of hibernation on and off. I mean, I usually hibernate my machine instead of shutting it down, and I need to know if there is a registry or log file that can tell me when I used my computer in the last few days.

I use Debian Jessie (8.7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This information is included in `/var/log/syslog` (and its rotated versions). I get my recent suspend to RAM periods by

```
zegrep -h 'Suspending system...|System resumed' /var/log/syslog*
```

You should probably use `Hibernating system...` instead, check your logs to make sure.